# Upgrading Angular Project from Version 11 to 16 - Import Errors in NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-module, angular-upgrade

I'm currently in the process of updating an existing Angular project from version 11 to version 16. I've successfully managed the transition up to version 15, but I've encountered a challenge upon reaching version 16.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm encountering the following error message for most of my modules:

"This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule."

My node version: 16.16.0

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fuse",
  "version": "11.0.0",
  "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "start:dev": "node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration dev",
    "start:dev:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration dev",
    "build": "ng build --aot",
    "build:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production --aot",
    "build:prod:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --aot",
    "build:dev:mem": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration dev --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "16.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "16.2.1",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.6.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "7.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "3.8.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "16.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "18.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "8.2.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-gantt": "20.1.60",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.16.2",
    "angular-calendar": "0.28.22",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.11.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "2.0.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "core-js": "3.32.0",
    "d3": "5.16.0",
    "date-fns": "2.16.1",
    "file-saver": "2.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.27",
    "ng2-charts": "2.4.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "ngx-color-picker": "10.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "10.1.1",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.10",
    "ngx-papaparse": "5.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "14.3.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "15.2.2",
    "ngx-ui-tour-core": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-tour-md-menu": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-vcard": "3.0.24",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.5",
    "prismjs": "1.25.0",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "text-mask-addons": "3.8.0",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "xlsx": "0.17.4",
    "zone.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.5",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.165",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "karma": "6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

I'm eager to learn and understand the potential reasons behind this error. Could someone kindly shed some light on why this might be happening? Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this could be due to a component being imported into multiple modules.

Comment: Afaik you also get this error when the imported module/class has errors, so you want to properly check if there are any errors in your components/services/modules etc...

Comment: @Alexus, but it had worked before I updated the angular version.

Comment: I've also got this error:
 This likely means that the library (ngx-ui-tour-md-menu) which declares TourMatMenuModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.